# How do I iconify and deiconify specific windows with object oriented code on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I see there are many similar questions about this on here, but I can't see one that answers it when using many windows and objected oriented.

I am new to object oriented so I dont really understand how to deiconify different windows. My aim is that when I press a 'back' button it will destroy the current window and then deiconify the previous window (which was iconified when the new window opened).

I use this code, to open the window when a button is pressed:

```
def openselect(self):
        self.selectedRace = self.viewBox.get()
        self.newwindow=Toplevel(self.master)
        racedetailsWindow(self.newwindow,self.selectedRace)
        self.master.iconify()

class racedetailsWindow():
    def __init__(self,master,selectedRace):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Race Details")
        self.master.geometry("650x400")
        self.master.config(bg="white")
```

And then this is the code for when I try to press back on the window to get back to the previous window. The previous window is called enterWindow

```
 #buttons: back button and enter button
    self.back = Button(self.master, text ="Back",command = self.close,width=10,fg="red").place(x=500,y=350)
    self.enter = Button(self.master,text="ENTER!",font=(15),command=self.gotoenter,width=15,fg="red").place(x=10,y=350)

def close(self):
    #enterWindow.deiconify()
    self.master.destroy()
```